# jQuery autocomplete for multiple fields using id, but not using class; using serialize if possible

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML input fields

```
<input type="text" name="partner_name_or_description[]" id="partner_name_or_description1" class="row_changed1"/>
<input type="text" name="partner_name_or_description[]" id="partner_name_or_description2" class="row_changed2"/>
<input type="text" name="partner_name_or_description[]" id="partner_name_or_description3" class="row_changed3"/>
```

Part of jquery autocomplete code (that works)

```
$("#partner_name_or_description1:input, #partner_name_or_description2:input, #partner_name_or_description3:input").autocomplete(
"__autocomplete_source.php",
```

In jquery there are: partner_name_or_description1, 2, 3 etc.... Instead of this long list of 1, 2, 3 etc. want to use something short with serialize (or in other possible way).

At first get these 1,2,3... with this code

```
$('[id^="partner_name_or_description"]').each(function (index, partner_name_or_description) {
var s_id = partner_name_or_description.id.substring(27);
});
```

Then instead of that long list trying to make something like this

```
$("#partner_name_or_description" + s_id + " :input").serialize().autocomplete(
```

It does not work. If View source, see

```
 $("#partner_name_or_description" + s_id + " :input").serialize().autocomplete(
```

Do not understand reason... May be incorrectly use `serialize().autocomplete`

Or may be must not use `serialize()` and must use something else.

I can not use `class="row_changedX"` because it is necessary for other purposes (class must be like row_changed1, 2, 3; for each row class name must be different).

**Working code**

```
/*Actually do not understand why this is necessary, but if I delete all uncommented, then code does not work*/
function findValue(li) {
/*if( li == null ) return alert("No match!");
// if coming from an AJAX call, let's use the CityId as the value
if( !!li.extra ) var sValue = li.extra[0];
// otherwise, let's just display the value in the text box
else var sValue = li.selectValue;
alert("The value you selected was: " + sValue);*/
}

function selectItem(li) {
findValue(li);
}

function formatItem(row) {
return row[0] + " (id: " + row[1] + ")";
}

$('[id^="partner_name_or_description"]').autocomplete("__autocomplete_source.php",
{
delay:10,
minChars:2,
matchSubset:1,
matchContains:1,
cacheLength:10,
onItemSelect:selectItem,
onFindValue:findValue,
formatItem:formatItem,
autoFill:true
}//{ delay:10,
)//.autocomplete(;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: Thanks to @jk -- this will work:

```
$('[id^="partner_name_or_description"]').autocomplete(
        "__autocomplete_source.php",
        //do stuff
});
```

Comment: Why not `$('[id^="partner_name_or_description"]').autocomplete("__autocomplete_source.php",//...more code here});` Is the `each()` necessary?

Comment: Good point, I don't believe it should be, ill include that in answer, thx!

Comment: Thank you jk. Your suggestion works. I will paste whole code for information